# Issues in php dom output

Tags: php, html, dom

i am working with php dom and i have read this code to php variable with html included in the  string,but there is some issues with the output and iam posting some piece of code over here

```
              $html = '<html>
                   <body>   
                
                 <img src="home/ex.png">     

                   <?php 
                    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                    {
                    echo $i;
                    };
                    ?>
                   </body> 
                   </html>';
                    
                    $dom = new DOMDocument();
                    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
                    $img = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
                    $img->item(0)->setAttribute('style', '');
                    $dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
                    $m=htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($dom->saveHTML()));
```

**i want php to print like this**

```
                   <html>
                   <body style=" ">  

               <img src="home/ex.png"> 
   
                   <?php for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                    {
                    echo $i;
                    };
                    ?>
                   </body> 
                   </html>
```

**but it showing the error like this**

```
                    <html>
                    <body>
  <img src="home/ex.png">   
                    <?php 
                    for(int i=0;i 10; i )
                    {
                    echo $i;
                    };
                    ?>
                    </body> 
                    </html>
```

**but all plus operators and  less than sign are missing from output**

Comment: I think using `urldecode` is causing a lot of your problems.

Comment: Where and how are you printing this?

Comment: printing in a file

Comment: urldecode is necessary, if it not used it will encode some links

Comment: Is your *entire HTML* a URL? No. So applying `urldecode` to it makes no sense. So, if I understood correctly, what you're doing here is grabbing the contents of a file, making some minor changes and then saving the file with new contents?